# BIM 360 Is there a way of retrieving the account_id on behalf of the authorized user

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am attempting to build an integration into our web application which allows user's to link their BIM360 account with our account. The ultimate goal is to call the BIM360 API and pull projects on behalf of the Authenticated user.

I am not seeing a way of obtaining the user's account id so that I can make a request to this api  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/projects on the user's behalf.

Comment: Have you tried with https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/ ? It will return the hubs this user has access, in which the hub id with prefix 'b.'  is BIM 360 hub. After removing 'b.', it is same to account_id if working with BIM 360 API

Comment: @XiaodongLiang that appears to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/ resource is able to provide me with what I need.